# Link Content Control to Legacy Form Field in MSFT Word (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm sure this question has an easy answer, but I have a short timeline and need to get it resolved ASAP.

I'd like to have a content control drop down that when the user makes a selection, will update a legacy text box formField with the selected value.

I have no trouble selecting form fields and setting them using VBA code:

ActiveDocument.FormFields("MyFieldName").Result

But I'm having trouble selecting the value from the content control, and also figuring out how to execute the macro "onExit" like I can with legacy fields / drop downs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google "vba content control events".

For example, see the last post by Greg Maxey at [how-to-catch-custom-control-events-with-vba-macro](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3c99905c-60dd-444d-b4f1-9781c95ca4e9/how-to-catch-custom-control-events-with-vba-macro?forum=worddev) and towards the bottom of his page http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html